# Failure to find com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.9.6 in https://jitpack.io was cached in the local repository

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I start a maven project my maven project pom.xml file not install all depency I install my project I take an error
 "Failure to find com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.9.6 in https://jitpack.io was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced" error . Pelase help me ?

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like the dependency wouldn't be fetched until the local caching time expires.
You can try "mvn -U install" command to try fetch the dependencies everytime.